# How to create a webhook on a repository on the GitHub web api using AJAX?

Tags: api, github, webhooks, http-status-code-400

I am experimenting with Webhooks in the GitHub api. I got one working by doing it manually as in going into my repository and clicking into the setting and enabling a web hook. But now I want to do this in AJAX and I am getting problems. Anytime I try to send a POST to the web api it fails with a 400 (Bad Request). I am not sure where I am going wrong with my code.

```
function createWebHooksOnRepos(token){
const webhookURL = "https://api.github.com/repos/DanoBuck/AlgorithmsAndDataStructures/hooks";

const json = {
    "name": "WebHook",
    "active": true,
    "events": [
        "issue_comment",
        "issues"
    ],
    "config": {
        "url": "http://39a40427.ngrok.io/api/webhooks/incoming/github",
        "content_type": "json"
        }
};
$.ajax({
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Token " + token
    },
    url: webhookURL,
    data: json,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

}

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [github Webhook API doc](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/#create-a-hook) :

> name - string - Required. Use "web" for a webhook or use the name of a valid
>   service. (See [/hooks](https://api.github.com/hooks) for the list of valid service names.)

So in your case, just rename `Webhook` to `web` :

```
const json = {
    "name": "web",
    "active": true,
    "events": [
        "issue_comment",
        "issues"
    ],
    "config": {
        "url": "http://39a40427.ngrok.io/api/webhooks/incoming/github",
        "content_type": "json"
        }
};
```

Also `JSON.stringify` your data before sending :

```
$.ajax({
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Token " + token
    },
    url: webhookURL,
    data: JSON.stringify(json),
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Still no luck with this. Still receiving the same response back "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)" . Thank you for your help though.

Comment: You forgot to stringify the data, I've updated my post

Comment: data: JSON.stringify(json), - That line makes it work perfectly. Thank you very much for your help. Appreciate the help greatly.